# Cant run tools(PHP-Auth/delight-im) inside vendor

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I am trying to run this password authentication https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Auth#creating-a-new-instance

I follow their's tutorial as also composer's.

Directories:

```
Main
   |
   ->src
   |   |
   |   ->tools
   |         |
   |         ->authentication
   |         |
   |         ->db
   |
   ->vendor
```

composer

```
 {
"name": "***",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Source\\": "src/"
    }
},
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "***",
        "email": "***"
    }
],
"require": {
    "delight-im/auth": "dev-master",
    "cboden/ratchet": "^0.4",
    "laravel/laravel": "^5.8",
    "twig/twig":"^2.0",
}
```

}

File inside authentication folder:

```
require_once "../../../vendor/autoload.php";

use Source\tools\db;

$dbConfig = new db\dbconfig("users");

$credentials = $dbConfig->setDb();

$pdo_connection =  new PDO("mysql:host=$localhost;dbname=$database_schema",
                   $credentials["UserName"], $credentials["PassWord"]);

$auth = new \Delight\Auth\Auth($pdo_connection);
```

File inside db folder

```
namespace Source\tools\db;
class dbconfig  
{
  .....
}
```

I can use **use Source\tools\db;** to define **dbconfig** so i guess autoload is working for this.

But when trying to use this line of code **$auth = new \Delight\Auth\Auth($pdo_connection);** I get the following error:
**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Delight\Auth\Auth' not found in (removed dir for privacy)/src/tools/authentication/validate_login_credentials.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in**

I am new to **namespace/composer** please excuse my ignorance on this.

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried and it's working in this way, at the top

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

After that the DB configuration

```
$db = new \PDO('mysql:dbname=my-database;host=localhost;charset=utf8mb4', 'my-username', 'my-password');

$auth = new \Delight\Auth\Auth($db);

echo get_class($auth);
```

There are no errors, double check your vendor autoload file, it seems you are inputting wrong path.

Update your composer file with the following

```
"require": {
    "delight-im/auth": "dev-master", // "delight-im/auth": "^8.1"
    "cboden/ratchet": "^0.4",
    "laravel/laravel": "^5.8",
    "twig/twig":"^2.0",
 }
```

Replace

```
"delight-im/auth": "dev-master",
```

with

```
"delight-im/auth": "^8.1"
```

save and execcute composer update command.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. But it doesnt work for me if i change the ```require``` as you suggested

gives me this error

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/media/world/mywork/dev/WebDev/src/tools/authentication/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in

Comment: I knew I should have used a proper version. but i couldnt find which was the latest. how did you find out?
Also I had to revert back to ```require_once "../../../vendor/autoload.php";``` in order to work